# Post back with Dojo Dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dojo

I have a dojo dropdown and I want to add a post back even to it. This is because I want to load other controls based on the value selected from the drop down. How can I achieve something like this? This is ASP.NET MVC.

Here is what I have.

```
@model String
@{
    var id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty);
    var name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty);    
}
<select title="Country" name="dropDownList" id="dropDownList" style="width: 140px">    
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="UK">UK</option>        
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
        dojo.connect(dojo.byId('#dropDownList'), "onchange", function (evt) {
            //var selectedVal = dojo.byId('#dropDownList').get('value');                        
            alert("changed!");
            location.href = '/Provisioning/Country';
            //alert(selectedVal);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am able to get the alert and also able to stop @ the break point in controller. But how can I now pass my value selected???

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: You need to show us some code of what you are doing and what you have tried.  If we have a page and your control and what you want to happen, people can show you what to do.

Comment: I have added the code. Please review it and let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score -2):

```
var _data = [
                { objectid: 10, district: "dist1", meterid: "meter10", premise: "premise1", blinkcount: 100 },
                { objectid: 11, district: "dist1", meterid: "meter11", premise: "premise100", blinkcount: 200 },
                { objectid: 12, district: "dist3", meterid: "meter160", premise: "premise1", blinkcount: 100 },
                { objectid: 13, district: "dist3", meterid: "meter12", premise: "premise101", blinkcount: 300 },
                { objectid: 14, district: "dist1", meterid: "meter180", premise: "premise1", blinkcount: 100 },
                { objectid: 15, district: "dist2", meterid: "meter13", premise: "premise102", blinkcount: 400 },
                { objectid: 16, district: "dist3", meterid: "meter1", premise: "premise1", blinkcount: 100 },
                { objectid: 17, district: "dist2", meterid: "meter14", premise: "premise103", blinkcount: 500 }];


        let districtdata = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
            districtdata.push({ id: i, label: _data[i].district });
        }
        let meterdata = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
            meterdata.push({ id: i, label: _data[i].meterid });
        }
        let premisedata = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
            premisedata.push({ id: i, label: _data[i].premise });
        }

        let diststore = Observable(new Memory({
            data: districtdata
        }));
        let distos = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: diststore });

        let meterstore = Observable(new Memory({
            data: meterdata
        }));
        let meteros = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: meterstore });

        let premisestore = Observable(new Memory({
            data: districtdata
        }));
        let premiseos = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: premisestore });

        let district = new Select({
            store: distos
        }, "district");
        district.startup();

        var meter = new Select({
            store: meteros
        }, "meter");
        meter.startup();



        var premise = new Select({
            store: premiseos
        }, "premise");
        premise.startup();



        district.on("change", function () {
            console.log("my value: ", this.get("value"));

            meterdata = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
                if (_data[i].district === this.options[this.get("value")].label) {
                    meterdata.push({ id: i, label: _data[i].meterid });
                }
            }
            meterstore = Observable(new Memory({
                data: meterdata
            }));
            meteros = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: meterstore });
            meter.setStore(meteros);

        })

        meter.on("change", function () {
            console.log("my value: ", this.get("value"))
        })

        premise.on("change", function () {
            console.log("my value: ", this.get("value"))
        })
```